# Issue Connecting to MongoDB Atlas From Docker App hosted on Google Platform

Tags: mongodb, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mongodb-atlas

the issue:

This what happens when I curl the endpoint http://ip/getuser/

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:542:21)
at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:272:3)
at cb (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:221:5)
at maybePromise (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:714:3)
at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:217:10)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:427:22)
at exports.IsCardActivated (/app/routes/index.js:47:45)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing in
side of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (re
jection id: 2)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejectio
ns that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

router/getuserbydetails

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
require('dotenv').config()

function connectUrl() {
  return process.env.url;
}


exports.GetUserDetails = async (req, res) => {
....

    if (!client) client = await MongoClient.connect(connectUrl(), { useNewUrlParser: true })
    const db = client.db(getDatabaseName());

  ....

};
```

./index.js

```
var user= require('./routes/user/index');
app.get('/getuser', user.getuser);
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
ENV NODE_ENV="production"

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Google Platform: GCE instance setting:

[image: This is a picture of the Instance Setting I am using. I have the https enabled but the Http setting disabled, The instance type is N1 as standard and I have made the instance containerized optimized OS- which is provided by Google, I've allowed default access, network settings is being handled by a load balancer and firewall]
**Note**:

**firewall**:
 allow 443, 80

using LB on in front of the application.

This application works fine locally I'm wondering where it might be going wrong.

Comment: Did you print `process.env.url` & check what you're getting ? If you possible can you put fake username&password&servername and give us ur connection string ?

Comment: @whoami   let me have a look

Comment: `connect_url=mongodb+srv:/user:pass@test01alph-tyx.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority` @whoami

Comment: after srv:// it should’ve two //

Comment: like : `mongodb+srv://user:pass@test01alph-tyx.gcp.mongodb.net//test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`? @whoami

Comment: nope only after srv:// , you can always login into atlas portal and get the url

Comment: @whoami I had a second look that doesn't seem to be issue i think i missed typed rather copy and pasting. here is the correct one `connect_url=mongodb+srv://user:pass@test01alph-tyx.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: It looks ok, why don't to execute the function first & take this value `mongodb+srv://user:pass@test01alph-tyx.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority` into a variable & pass it to mongo connect func, also you try without `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`

Comment: What about  your firewall roules?

Comment: Do you still have an issue? If yes please provide more information about your firewall configuration.